# given that the curve $x^3+ax^2+bx$ has no turning points show that $a^2<3b$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to work it using second derivative :
When the second derivative is 0, the first derivative should not change signs. But this seems extremely tricky to prove. Kindly help!

---

first derivative : $3x^2 + 2ax+b$
second derivative : $6x+2a$

Comment: isn't it enough for the first derivative to be always positive or negative? If so, imposing $3x^2+2ax+b>0$ gives you the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curve has no turning point when its derivative takes constant sign. This means it has no real roots. Thus $\triangle_{f'} < 0$. But $f'(x) = 3x^2 + 2ax + b$, so $(2a)^2 - 4(3)b < 0 \rightarrow a^2 - 3b < 0$.

Comment: Omg yes! thanks a lot xD I knew I was missing something nice and simple like this

Answer (score 3):

A differentiable function $f(x)$  has no turning points if its derivative $f'(x)$ has no real roots.
$f'(x) = 3x^2 + 2ax + b$, so the equation $3x^2 + 2ax + b = 0$ should have no roots. As $D = (2a)^2 + 4*3*b = 4a^2 - 12b$, we have the inequation $4a^2 - 12b < 0$ which can be written as $a^2 < 3b$. Q.E.D.

Comment: 'no rational roots' -> 'no real roots' perhaps?

Comment: thank you so much :) got it completely !

Comment: @BaronVT Sure, you're right. I meant real roots.