# Let $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ Prove that for $a^2\lt 3b$ there exists only one $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=0$

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Let $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ Prove that for $a^2\lt 3b$ there exists only one $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=0$

Now we know this $x_0$exists because of the IVT. Also graphing different values of a and b, I've come to the conclusion that if $a^2\lt 3b$ then there is indeed only one $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=0$. My question is why does the requirement $a^2\lt 3b$ cause there to be only one root?

Comment: Are we requiring $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Hint: If there are more than one root, then the polynomial has a local maximum or minimum between those roots. So if there are no local maxima/minima then there can be only one root.

Comment: @neil yes $x\in R$

Comment: @HenningMakholm how is it possible to determine that there are no local min or max with just the information we have?

Comment: @RonaldB: You have tagged the question [tag:calculus]. Does calculus provide you with some tools for investigating local maxima and minima?

Comment: Ohhh. Differentiating the polynomial and then solving the quadratic equation will give us the number of min/max. Was definitely overthinking. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [given that the curve $x^3+ax^2+bx$ has no turning points show that $a^2 \ < \ 3b$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/963949/given-that-the-curve-x3ax2bx-has-no-turning-points-show-that-a23b)

Answer (score 3):

$f'(x)=3x^2+2ax+b=3(x+\frac13a)^2-\frac13a^2+b>3(x+\frac13a)^2\ge 0$, so $f$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: +1 Yes, short and to the point!

Comment: @almagest but doesn't $3(x+\frac13a)^2\ge 0$ just show that's increasing, and not strictly increasing?

Comment: @RonaldB $\ge$ is good enough for strictly increasing where the $=$ is only at one point.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ has a turning point, a value of $c$ that places that turning point close enough to the horizontal axis will produce two real roots.  (And, because the limits as $x \rightarrow \infty$ and $x \rightarrow -\infty$ have opposite signs, there is eventually a third real root.)

So you need to ensure that $f$ has no turning points.  What this means is

> $f'(x) \neq 0$.  But $f'(x) = 3 x^2 + 2 a x + b$.  To ensure this has no zeroes, we require that it's discriminant, $(2a)^2 - 4(3)(b) < 0$, which simplifies to the inequality you have.